# How to calculate Laplace inverse of $\frac{1}{(s^{2}+1)^{2}}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Laplace inverse of $\frac{1}{(s^{2}+1)^{2}}$.

I have beaten my head about this but have not got a clue as to how to do it! Can someone help? I tried to express this as some form of a derivative, but I am really just not sure what to do since a derivative of $\frac{1}{s^{2}+1}$ would involve a 2s in the numerator. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you compute the forward transform of $f = \sin(t) - t \cos(t)$?

Comment: @mattos What was your rationale behind choosing that?

Comment: Experience, though you could probably deduce it by considering the Laplace transforms of $\sin(t), \cos(t)$ and $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(s)=\frac{1}{(s^{2}+1)^{2}}=\frac{2s}{(s^{2}+1)^{2}} \times \dfrac 1 {2s}$$
$$F(s)=- \dfrac {d}{ds}\left  (\frac{1}{(s^{2}+1)} \right) \times \dfrac 1 {2s}$$
$$F(s)=G(s) H(s)$$
And their inverse Laplace Transform are:
$$g(t)=t \sin t \,\, , h(t)=\dfrac 12$$
Then use the convolution theorem. Evaluate this integral:
$$f(t)=\int_0^t g(\tau) h(t-\tau)  d \tau$$
$$f(t)=\int_0^t  \tau \sin (\tau) \times \dfrac 12 d \tau$$

For the Convolution Theorem look here formula 33
[here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/laplace_table.aspx)

You should find:
$$f(t)=\dfrac 12 (\sin t - t\cos t)$$

Comment: Could you point me to tje convoluyion theorem?

Comment: Open the link it's formula 33  @user00000000001899